# How to add external js file in Nuxt?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have js file called script.js in assets/js. Tried to include in nuxt.config.js like below:

```
head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ],
      script: [
          { src: '/assets/js/script.js', ssr: false }
      ]
  }
```

But getting 'GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/js/script.js 404 (OK)'.

Answer (score 11):

Simply keep your ***script.js*** file into ***static*** folder, because ***static*** folder treat as root folder.

and add the path into ***nuxt.config.js*** configuration file like below

```
script: [
          { src: '/script.js'}
      ]
```

Comment: This does not work if you use the router to redirect to a page.

Answer (score 4):

here is the best way that worked for me

put your `script.js` file in `plugins` folder and then go and include it in *`nuxt.config.js`*

```js
  // Plugins to run before rendering page (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins)
  plugins: [
    '@/plugins/script.js'
  ],
```

remember that `@` in `nuxt.js` or `vue.js` means root folder

Comment: how to use it in pages or components?

Comment: @JenuelGanawed This gets automatically added to nuxt context object so where ever you access nuxt context object your plugin will be included you can check here https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/plugins/

Answer (score 1):

In this method, your js files must be in the path **static** folder
and add this code to you *.vue files you want to use

```
     export default {
head() {
return {
  link: [
    {
      rel: "stylesheet",
      href:
        "/assets/css/bootstrap.css"
    },
  ],
  script: [
    {
      src: "assets/js/bootstrap.js",
      body: true
    },
  ],
    }
  }
```