# how to import internal global JS in nuxt.config.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

How do I add a global JS file to the nuxt config?

```
module.exports = {
 /*
 ** Global CSS
 */
 css: ['~/assets/css/main.css'],
/*
** Global JS
*/
js: ['~/assets/js/main.js']
```

}

> It does not work obviously.
>
> ### any ideas?

Comment: What is the purpose of you global file ? XY problem suspected.

Comment: You would want to look at [plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/).

Comment: @mathk i have JS folder and i need to link up with my nuxt project

Comment: @priyeshvadhiya Doing `import ...` as needed wouldn't work ?

Comment: @mathk not working

Answer (score 2):

Simply keep your **script.js** file into **static** folder, because **static** folder treat as root folder.

and change **nuxt.config.js** configuration file like below

```
module.exports = {
//Global JS
script: [
        { src: '/script.js'}
        ]
........
..........

}
```

you can see another solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52495601/how-to-add-external-js-file-in-nuxt/52499653#52499653)

Comment: you should keep your js file in root folder , because when you build Nuxt generate then global js file not place into root. so you have to do it manually. thanks :)